# What are good Hindi or Kannada translations of Jayadeva's Gita Govinda (Sanskrit)?

Tags: krishna, sanskrit, radha

I'm looking for a verse-by-verse prose translation of Jayadeva's Gita Govinda. Similar to what Gorakhpur Gita Press has done for Valmiki Ramayanam, Mahabharata, and others. Any suggestions welcome!